# Splitting polygons between two shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, overlapping-features, splitting

In QGIS I have two overlapping shapefiles. Is there any way, where I can select polygons from the 1st shapefile and trim everything that overlaps with them, in the 2nd shapefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`"Difference"`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference) processing tool shall work.

Can be found under `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Difference`.